# How do I get my iPhone and Apple Watch to beta together?

Tags: ios, upgrade, watchos, beta

At August 8, 2019, 01:55 UTC+8, from Apple's Feedback Assistant I'm told that:

> Warning You must update your watch to watchOS 6 beta 2 or later before updating to iOS 13 beta 6 otherwise your watch will no longer be able to connect to your phone. (52854192)

I've had the iOS 13 Beta Software configuration profile on my iPhone, but it only takes me to iOS 13 beta 6, nothing below. Yet if I upgrade to beta 6, I will not be able to upgrade my watch.

Also I've had watchOS 6 beta's profile on my iPhone, but I seem to have to upgrade my phone first.

Is there a way to upgrade to iOS 13 beta 5 or lower, or is it that the only way for me is to wait until September's release?

Comment: So your iphone is still on IOS 13 beta 5 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. After a dozen hours then Apple has tweaked to their documentation. When watch is still on OS 5, you can upgrade iPhone first, then watch to OS 6 beta without issue.